# variance decomposition in factor models

Tags: variance, factor-analysis, risk, decomposition

Consider a linear model

$\textbf{y} = \pmb{\beta}'\textbf{x} + \pmb{\varepsilon}$

with $\textbf{y}$ a $N \times 1$ vector of random variables, $\pmb{\beta}$ a $N \times K$ vector and $\textbf{x}$ a $K \times 1$ vector of random variables and $\pmb{\varepsilon}$ is a $N \times 1$ vector. In other words, I have a $K$-factor model for $\textbf{y}$.

The model variance is

$Var(\textbf{y}) = \pmb{\beta}' \pmb{\Sigma_x}\pmb{\beta} +  \pmb{\Sigma_{\varepsilon}}$

where $\pmb{\Sigma}_x$ denotes the variance covariance matrix of x.

I want to decompose the variance according to the constributions from the different X's. This is possible thanks to the Euler decomposition for homogeneous functions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function).

My question is: how do I compute

$\frac{d Var(\textbf{y})}{d \textbf{x}}$?